# Design ideas for managing multiple third party apis with separate authentication methods

Tags: python, rest, oop, authentication, design-patterns

Trying to figure out the best approach to design for the following:

We have a `REST API` that is going to fetch plant data. We have a few third party plant data providers.

1. Each provider has its own `REST API`
2. Each provider has its own authentication/authorization method (OAuth1.0, 2.0, etc)
3. We aren't guaranteed that the authentication methods are the same

A request to our main `REST API` will *switch* based on provider, so different logic will be handled for each provider. In turn we will need to *pull down* the appropriate authentication for the third party api.

Here are a few design features I have locked down to start off:

- definitely going to need an external cache to store the various providers access tokens
- going to implement a few functions like `get_token` and `refresh_token`
- The `AuthToken` will look something like:

```
@dataclass
class AuthToken:
   access_token: str
   expiration_date: int
   generation_date: int
   refresh_token: str


   def get_access_token(self):
       pass

   def refresh_token(self):
       pass
```

I have these ideas floating around, but the class design for this authentication stuff is evading me. so any help there would be awesome. I also included a few ideas below.

Ideas:

- Creating an implicit interface with `Protocols` and then having each provider have its own `ProviderAuthToken` class. So when we switch based on provider we just pass in its respective `AuthToken` class.
- Maybe I'll need an `Authentication` class to store the provider's necessary variables to like generate a JWT or whatever we may need.

Probably missing a whole bunch of stuff, but thanks a ton for any help. I'm new to the field as well so any general tips are welcome!

Other considerations:

- using lambda
- using python

Also took inspiration from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69713852/best-practises-for-consuming-multiple-third-party-apis-in-existing-api)! :)

Comment: There are a lot of design patterns and ideas you can use for interacting with REST APIs. Firstly I'd suggest looking into the `requests` library as it provides a nice layer of abstraction around making the requests. If looking for other inspiriation you can check out other projects that interact with external APIs, for example [this project](https://github.com/rnag/wystia) that I've recently worked on, for interfacing with a media management service in particular, whose API is well documented.